# check whether the time has expired or not

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, timestamp

hi guys how checking date expired or not?
i'm use clear JS.
I think it only checks for days, and I need it all together

I want the check to be done correctly, but it's like it checks for a day instead of an hour or something.

```js
var date = new Date();
let add_day = date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
let minus_day = date.setDate(date.getDate() - 2); // x
let fors = (...args) => (new Date(args[0]));


console.log(add_day + ' | add days | ' + fors(add_day).toLocaleString());
console.log(minus_day + ' | minus day | ' + fors(minus_day).toLocaleString());

if (add_day > minus_day) { 
  console.log('date has expired')
} else {
  console.log('date has not expired')
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to add **" +1 hours "** in code ?

Comment: I want to check, up to the hour of today, whether the date (+hours) has passed or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating the (date) variable twice, which eventually ended up with both days the same. Try to create a new Date like the below

```js
var date1 = new Date();
var date2 = new Date();
let add_day = date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + 1);
let minus_day = date2.setDate(date2.getDate() - 0 );
let fors = (...args) => (new Date(args[0]));


console.log(new Date(minus_day))
console.log(new Date(add_day))

console.log(add_day + ' | add days | ' + fors(add_day).toLocaleString());
console.log(minus_day + ' | minus day | ' + fors(minus_day).toLocaleString());

if (add_day > minus_day) { 
  console.log('date has expired')
} else {
  console.log('date has not expired')
}
```

Comment: when we compare the date, does it check the second and the clock? Not just a new day

Comment: By default, when you use the comparison operator in dates, it will compare everything in the order as follows year -> month -> date -> day -> minutes -> seconds -> milliseconds

Comment: @HariPrasad—no it doesn't. It coerces values to number, so for *Date* instances it compares the time values, i.e. milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970 UTC. `add_day > minus_day` is identical to `add_day.getTime() > minus_day.getTime()` where the [*getTime*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method returns the time value (not the clock time).

Answer (score 0):

Output:

[image]

You can see that I added **+30 seconds** to date and it is working properly

```js
var date = new Date();
let add_day  = new Date(date);

// add_day.setDate(date.getDate() + 1); // Add one day to today's date
add_day.setSeconds(add_day.getSeconds() + 30); // Add 30 seconds to the expiration date

let minus_day = date.setDate(date.getDate())
let fors = (...args) => (new Date(args[0]));

console.log(' add days | ' + fors(add_day).toLocaleString());
console.log(' minus day | ' + fors(minus_day).toLocaleString());

if (add_day > minus_day) { 
  console.log('date has expired')
} else {
  console.log('date has not expired')
}
```

Comment: when we compare the date, does it check the second and the clock? Not just a new day

Comment: You can see I added +30 seconds instead of day , and it is working properly .

Comment: @user21339222—see my comment to @HariPrasad [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75647470/257182).